# pstricks multido variable not accepted

Tags: pstricks, multido

the following Example does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}

\begin{document}

\def\FF{x 3 exp 4 mul 3 div x sub 1 add}
\def\AbFF{x 2 exp 4 mul 1 sub}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2)(2.5,4)
\psaxes[Dx=1,Dy=1]{->}(0,0)(-2,-1.5)(2.2,3.7)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psplot[plotstyle=curve,linewidth=1.5pt]{-1.3}{1.2}{\FF}% postscript function
\def\xs{-1}
\multido{\r=-1+0.5}{5}{
\psplotTangent{\r}{1.3}{\FF}
\psdot[dotscale=1.2](! \r /x \r def \AbFF)
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem ist the second \r in the line:

```
\psdot[dotscale=1.2](! \r /x \r def \AbFF)
```

If I replace it with a number, then everything works fine.

Comment: This is very similar to [How to define a global constant in postscript statement?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24205/5764) You need to use `! \r\space /x \r\space def \AbFF` as TeX gobbles the space after a control sequence, which is problematic for PostScript.